# Thread.Sleep inside a Thread callback hangs Windows

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I'm starting a Thread that runs routine tasks with some Files, unfortunately, calling `Thread.Sleep` inside that thread callback hangs up Windows for the specified time, ie. my cursor freezes and CTRL+ALT+DEL does nothing either. How do I specifically "Sleep" the background thread without hanging up the UI?

I'm creating the thread using this:

```
 createThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.createFileExec));
 createThread.Start();
```

And my callback is like this:

```
    private void createFileExec() {
        ....
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        ....
    }
```

Comment: That all looks okay.. Are you sure it's making it to the thread? Is the thread maybe invoking a delegate that hangs in a loop?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the method code?

Comment: Wait do you mean your entire OS is frozen or just the app window?

Comment: @Tudor entire OS i guess , because he says ctrl+alt+del does nothing either .

Comment: @rajat: That's very weird then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I specifically "Sleep" the background thread without hanging up the UI?

That's exactly what you are doing by calling `Thread.Sleep` on your new thread. Are you sure you aren't calling `createFileExec` from the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

James is right, there is no reason for the UI to hang .

A quick hack that you can try is to use loops instead of Thread.Sleep .

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
{
      Console.WriteLine("."); //To know that the thread is asleep.
}
```